# sort an array by comparing a string value swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to sort an array by comparing a string value from two items, the values of the property are a number but of type String. How can I convert them to Int and check which is greater. Current code looks like this.

```
libraryAlbumTracks = tracks.sorted {
            $0.position!.compare($1.position!) == .orderedAscending
        }
```

but values like "13" come before "2" because it's a string. I tried to cast the values to Int but because they are optional, I get the error that `operand ">" cannot be applied to type Int?`
Please how can I go around this in the sorted function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide the `numeric` option when using `compare`. This will properly sort strings containing numbers and it also works if some of the string don't actually have numbers or the strings have a combination of numbers and non-numbers.

```
libraryAlbumTracks = tracks.sorted {
    $0.position!.compare($1.position!, options: [ .numeric ]) == .orderedAscending
}
```

This avoids the need to convert the strings to `Int`.

**Note**: You should also avoid force-unwrapping `position`. Either don't make them optional if it's safe to force-unwrap them, or safely unwrap then or use `??` to provide an appropriate default when comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

```
libraryAlbumTracks = tracks.sorted {
    guard let leftPosition = $0.position, 
          let leftInt = Int(leftPosition),
          let rightPosition = $1.position,
          let rightInt = Int(rightPosition) else { 
        return false 
    }
    return leftInt > rightInt
}
```